# Org-mode property to make subtree visibility bimodal?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a property I can set on a headline that makes `Tab` / `(org-cycle)` show everything in the subtree (i.e., effectively call `(outline-show-subtree)`)?

Whereas subtree cycling rotates a subtree among the three states, `FOLDED`, `CHILDREN`, and `SUBTREE`, I would like to limit the state space to just `FOLDED` and `SUBTREE` for select subtrees. This mechanism implicitly indicates that a particular subtree is meant to be viewed as an atomic unit, which is helpful for incorporating complete documents within an Org-mode tree. I find the alternative somewhat distracting—i.e., identifying the right subtree to expand, hitting `Tab` twice, and visually confirming whether I'm in the right location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good job for [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

```
(advice-add 'org-cycle :around #'my/org-cycle)

(defun my/toggle-bimodal-cycling (&optional pos)
  "Enable/disable bimodal cycling behavior for the current heading."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((enabled (org-entry-get pos "BIMODAL-CYCLING")))
    (if enabled
        (org-entry-delete pos "BIMODAL-CYCLING")
      (org-entry-put pos "BIMODAL-CYCLING" "yes"))))

(defun my/org-cycle (fn &optional arg)
  "Make org outline cycling bimodal (FOLDED and SUBTREE) rather than trimodal (FOLDED, CHILDREN, and SUBTREE) when a heading has a :BIMODAL-CYCLING: property value."
  (interactive)
  (if (and (org-at-heading-p)
           (org-entry-get nil "BIMODAL-CYCLING"))
      (my/toggle-subtree)
    (funcall fn arg)))

(defun my/toggle-subtree ()
  "Show or hide the current subtree depending on its current state."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (outline-back-to-heading)
    (if (not (outline-invisible-p (line-end-position)))
        (outline-hide-subtree)
      (outline-show-subtree))))
```

Answer (score 1):

ebpa's answer is quite nice, and I've already started using it.

One thing about it, though, is that it leaves a `:PROPERTIES:` drawer hanging open, which I find ugly.

You can totally hide the drawer with the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode/17492723#17492723), although
 you have to hide all of them, and there's no nice way to hint that they're hidden, nor to re-show them.  I haven't decided yet if I'm going to stick with that approach.